# Loading internal page

Tags: pages

How can I load another page in wordpress? For example, I created a post called "Services" and want it to be associated with a page-services page. My index is thus:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php
        break;
    endwhile;
else:
    ?>
    Nenhum post encontrado
<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you want a 'page in a page'. This is very easy. Just use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-in-page/) plugin. It has support for widgets and shortcodes. Especially the shortcodes will be interesting for you.

The plugin description repeats that it's mission is to

> bring your Facebook posts and Twitter feeds to your blog.

You can ignore that, you should be able to use it for other purposes too.

The plugin has good reviews. 3 with 5 stars and 1 with 2 stars.
The minimum WordPress version needed is 3.0.1, but it doesn't work with versions after 3.8.3. If you are still using an outdated version you should really consider updating.

Good luck!